# Elements and functions separated by commas

Tags: javascript, syntax

What does this syntax means?

```
var _t = this, _resetProperties, _add_html5_events, _remove_html5_events, _stop_html5_timer, _start_html5_timer, _attachOnPosition, _onplay_called = false, _onPositionItems = [], _onPositionFired = 0, _detachOnPosition, _applyFromTo, _lastURL = null, _lastHTML5State;
```

Comment: Declares multiple variables using a single `var` statement. Really pretty basic part of the language that I'd expect you'd learn on day 1 when reading a beginner book or tutorial.

Comment: The comma lets you combine multiple `var` statements into one.  `var x, y;` is the same as `var x; var y;`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - It is not exactly the same. It would be `var x = y, z;`

Comment: @ManoloSalsas: So, then it's `var x = y; var z;`.  Close enough.

Comment: @ManoloSalsas: How is `var x = y, z;` the same as `var x; var y;`?

Comment: @cookiemonster - I know it is not the same. It was just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a bunch of variable declarations/initializations, separated by commas.  It's the same as:

```
var _t = this;
var _resetProperties;
var _add_html5_events;
var _remove_html5_events;
var _stop_html5_timer;
var _start_html5_timer;
var _attachOnPosition;
var _onplay_called = false;
var _onPositionItems = [];
var _onPositionFired = 0;
var _detachOnPosition;
var _applyFromTo;
var _lastURL = null;
var _lastHTML5State;
```

I don't like to mix initializations with declarations like this.  It is messy and not very readable.  If anything, group your declarations (without values), and only group initializations if they are related.  It doesn't functionally change the code, it only makes it a bit smaller (and harder to read in cases).